# CDate converts to different date format

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have this legacy system that needs to transfer to a new PC. I've transferred it to windows 10 PC with IIS 10. The problem is that `CDate` Function in VB.net uses a different date format. The date format should be MM/dd/yyyy. But whenever I start the system, it uses the format dd/MM/yyyy. I cannot change the code of the system since it is very old and cannot be built again and it has multiple codes where it uses the `CDate` function.

I have already changed the locale

[image: Locale]

[image: Locale2]

Whenever I run the system this error occurs

[image: Error]

I know this error because of the date format.
Here is a sample query
[image: Sample]

How to fix this?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I always thought that dates in SQL server where yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss so not sure that the query you've screenshotted here is a valid test.  That aside understand the hole you find yourself in.  Maybe better idea would be to jump on the superusers SO, they might be able to advise better on how to configure IIS for your required date formatting.  Assuming that you've restarted the machine which is sometimes required for changing things like regional settings

Comment: Would also suggest while not a short term fix, your system (especially a webapp) should not be reliant on the formatting of Date.  You should probably be working towards updating your system to treat dates as dates and not be doing any sort of direct string conversion and formatting

Comment: Show us the relevant code. Date format should rarely be an issue if you're doing things properly, so you're probably not doing things properly. If you're passing dates to SQL code as text then you're definitely not.

Comment: If you are getting dates as text via user input and then converting to `DateTime` for use further up the chain then perhaps use `Date.ParseExact` or `Date.TryParseExact` instead of `CDate`, so you get to specify the input format.

Comment: The format is irrelevant if the data is stored in a native date data type. You might have a problem that can't be fixed due to badly written legacy code. Please post the code that is causing this issue otherwise it is impossible to provide a suggestion. Going by the error it looks like you are using VB.Net inside ASP.Net?

Comment: You say below that you can modify the query? You could simply wrap the date literal in a `CONVERT` to convert it to a date data type, but you are cementing in your technical debt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try forcing culture via `web.config` using [GlobalizationSection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.globalizationsection?view=netframework-4.8) class:

```
<system.web>
    <globalization uiCulture="en-us" culture="en-us" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! I've been trying to fix this issue for weeks.

Answer (score 0):

The dateformat for sql query should be yyyy-MM-dd format. There for you can format the date in the code first by using

```
Format(Yourdate,"yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Comment: I can easily modify the query if it is possible. But since the system is old. I cannot modify the code